# Confusion with every() in JS

Tags: javascript

I was learning JS and wanted to try to use every(). So, here is the code:

```js
const thresholdValues = [30,90]; 
const RAG_INPUT_CONFIG = {};
RAG_INPUT_CONFIG.min = -1000;
RAG_INPUT_CONFIG.max = 1000;

 const arr = thresholdValues.every((item, index, array)=>{
    return item >= RAG_INPUT_CONFIG.min && item <= RAG_INPUT_CONFIG.max && array[index] < array[index + 1];
})

console.log(arr);
```

So, I expect that arr variable is true but it returns false I do not know why. If I change array[index + 1] to just 100 then all works as expected and I get true but with array[index + 1] it does not work and I get false. Thus, I really need your help.

Comment: think about what you get when `index` is equal to 1 (the last element in your thresholdValues). You'll get `array[2]` which is undefined

Comment: every() func return true if all the condition you have putted passes all the elements otherwise it return false.

and array[index+1] at the end of loop will return undefined and thats why your condition failing.here  ( 90 < undefined)

Comment: @NickParsons indeed - `array[1] < array[2]` ==> `90 < undefined` ==> `false`

Comment: @NickParsons, hey Nick thanks for your comments, yeah :D stupid me. Nick, I just wanted to ensure that the items's value are in ascending order. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can replace `array[index + 1]` with a the variable `nextItem`, which looks like `const nextItem = array[index + 1] === undefined ? Infinity : array[index + 1]`. This will check if the next item is undefined, if it is, it will use `Infity`, and any number is smaller than `Infinity` . If it is defined, it will use the next number